# inline-block element went down when child element is contained in it

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am developing a website. In my website I am showing two element side by side. Second element will have fixed width and but first element will take the rest of the space. So I wrote a simple HTML and CSS code like this.

html

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery-left">

    </div>
    <div class="gallery-right">

    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.gallery-left{
    padding-top: 0px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: calc( 100% - 100px);
}

.gallery-right{
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 96px;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

It displays like this:

[image]

It is working as expected as you can see the red and yellow boxes. But the problem is when I add an child element to HTML like this:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
        <div class="gallery-left">
                <h5>This is child element</h5>          
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-right">

        </div>
</div>
```

The whole left box went down like this:

[image]

How can I fix it? I set padding top and margin top zero for both boxes. Main parent element as well. But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `vertical-align: top;` to these inline-block elements. Something like that should work:

```
.gallery-left{
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc( 100% - 100px);
}

.gallery-right{
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 96px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. I will up vote ur answer later. Thz a lot.